# How do I put a cftooltip around a table row?

Tags: coldfusion, tooltip, tablerow

I'm trying to put a tooltip on a table row so that when you hover over any part of the row the tooltip displays. When I put the cftooltip tag around the entire table it works, and when I put it within a td element it works, but nothing displays when I put it around td or tr elements.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a snippet of code?

Answer (score 2):

I did this which seems to work.  Note the lack of ending `>` in the `<TD>` tag.  If you leave it in there, it displays as an extra `>`

```
<TD BGCOLOR=999999 <cftooltip sourceForTooltip="diabetic3_text.cfm?id=MET"></cftooltip> 
1)&nbsp;<b>MET</b>
</TD>
```

Answer (score -1):

Cftooltip has tooltip attribute which actually is the tooltip to be displayed. You need to pass your values here to display it as text when hovering over the row.